# How to create this UI using GridLayoutManager inside RecyclerView and fix span to left or right

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[image]
How to create this UI using recycler view and GridLayoutManager. The problem I am getting is placing the items to only at left position or only at right side in some cases.

Comment: Sometimes the item will come only at the right side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a metro-like UI.  Having never implemented it, I will point you to google.  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+metro+ui+library